# How do you print lists from within a list in rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, zip

Here's the list:

```
 alist = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12])
```

I need to print the list like this:

```
list1     list2     list3     list4
1          4         7         10
2          5         8         11
3          6         9         12
```

Here is my code so far:

```
for item in alist:
    print("{:>8.2f} {:>8.2f} {:>8.2f} {:>8.2f}".format(the meat and potato goes here))
```

Comment: `zip()` is your friend

Comment: im new to coding, can you please show me how zip would be used in this scenario master? thank you

Comment: check this [Zip in Python](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/zip-in-python-48cb4f70d013)

Comment: experiment with `for row in zip(*alist): print(row)`

Comment: (Strictly, that's a tuple of lists, but similar thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way:

```
alist = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12])
print('list1\tlist2\tlist3\tlist4')
for row in zip(*alist): 
    print('%d\t%d\t%d\t%d' % row)
```

Result:

```
list1   list2   list3   list4
1       4       7       10
2       5       8       11
3       6       9       12
```

Or using `.format()`:

```
print('list1\tlist2\tlist3\tlist4')
for row in zip(*alist):
    print('{0[0]}\t{0[1]}\t{0[2]}\t{0[3]}'.format(row))
```

Result:

```
list1   list2   list3   list4
1       4       7       10
2       5       8       11
3       6       9       12
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using `str.format`, `zip` and `*` unpacker.

```
alist = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12])
cols = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']

print("{:>8} {:>8} {:>8} {:>8}".format(*cols))

for item in zip(*alist):
    print("{:>8} {:>8} {:>8} {:>8}".format(*item))
```

Result:

```
   list1    list2    list3    list4
       1        4        7       10
       2        5        8       11
       3        6        9       12
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you!

Comment: @BurmesePapi, no problem. Please accept the answer (green tick on left) if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip`:

```
alist = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12])
print('  '.join('list{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(alist))))
for i in zip(*alist):
   print '\t'.join(['{}']*len(alist)).format(*i)
```

Output:

```
list1  list2  list3  list4
1       4      7     10
2       5      8     11
3       6      9     12
```